# Installing gnome-do on Debian 12 (Bookworm)

Tags: gnome, configure

While attempting to `./configure` gnome-do I have run into an issue that I cannot seem to resolve.  It's looking for gnome-desktop-sharp-2 but cannot find it.  I cannot seem to  find a suitable library to which to create a link and have become a bit stumped.  Gnome-do installs fine from apt in stretch but does not seem to exist beyond that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have attempted to locate suitable replacements (such as I did with gconf-2.0 by executing: `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gconf-2.0.pc /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gconf-sharp-2.0.pc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GNOME Do](https://github.com/gnome-do/core) was [removed from Debian in 2018](https://bugs.debian.org/911202), along with a number of obsolete GNOME libraries. As a result, you won’t find the libraries you’re looking for, and you won’t be able to “cheat” by linking similar libraries (which tends to cause problems anyway, even when it appears to work).

You *could* install the old packages from Debian 9, but you’d be better off looking for a similar program which is still available in Debian. Perhaps [kupfer](https://kupferlauncher.github.io/) would fit the bill; it’s available in Debian 12 (`sudo apt install kupfer`).